# Concrete Mathematics: Solving recurrence by transforming to sum-recurrence (equations 2.9, 2.10); how is 2.10 in closed form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In the book Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik) they present, in 2.9, the following general recurrence of the form

$$
a_nT_n = b_nT_{n-1} + c_n
$$

And go on to explain how a summation factor can be used to turn this into a sum-recurrence. Using this process they come up with a solution in 2.10

$$
T_n = \frac{1}{s_na_n}\biggl(s_1b_1T_0 + \sum_{k=1}^ns_kc_k\biggr)
$$

But there still appears be a summation that needs to be iterated over. Namely $\sum_{k=1}^ns_kc_k$; we still have to go from $k=1$ to $n$. This doesn't seem like something you'd find in a closed form solution.

They go on to give an example for $T_1$ ending up as $T_1 = (s_1b_1T_0 + s_1c_1)/s_1a_1$ but that's just for $T_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not say that using the summation factor will give you a closed form: they say that it will reduce the recurrence to a sum. If one is fortunate, the summation will be one that can be evaluated explicitly in closed form, but there is no guarantee that this will be the case. Indeed, in the example that they give, solving the recurrence (2.12), they get a closed form only in the sense that the harmonic numbers are considered known quantities, meaning that a result expressed in terms of them is considered closed in this context.

Comment: Ah I see, I was jumping to conclusions. Thanks for your speedy reply.

Comment: @FredClausen: You’re welcome.